# Continue executing loop after catching an exception in try/catch block

Tags: java, loops, exception, try-catch

How to continue the iteration loop if an exception occurs at **while (iterator.hasNext())**?

So I want to do something like below.

```
            try {
                loop: while (iterator.hasNext())  // as excetion is on this line excetion will be catch by catch_2
                {
                    try {
                        Result res = (Result) iterator.next();
                        list.add(res);
                    } catch (Exception e) {                    // catch_1
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {                            // catch_2
                // goto start of the loop
                continue loop;
            }

Iterator<UserProvisioning> iterator = beans.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    UserProvisioning userProvisioning = (UserProvisioning) iterator.next();
                    System.out.println(userProvisioning.getFIRST_NAME());
                    list.add(userProvisioning);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    logger.error("Error occured...)
                }
            }
```

As per my understanding iterator.hasNext() tries to check whether next element is present or not by mapping csv record column to POJO fields and as there is invalid data in csv record headers count do not matches record files hence error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
```

SO I am trying to log the error and continue to iterate next records.

**EDIT** 
`iterator.hasNext()` should return true or false but its throwing error

Comment: to what use? you want to throw exceptions into infinity? for instance: iterator is null, you want your logs to show millions upon millions of NPE's being logged? (you don't even log them)

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: why exception throws in hasNext? i never see that Iterator definition.

Comment: @suiwenfeng No, I have next elements(records) after exception record and as there are records after exception it means hasNext() should check the result for not null(and return true)

Comment: no, hasNext should return true or false, and no exception.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you put a try-catch block within your loop it will continue the loop to the end unless you break out of it

```
for(Iterator<UserProvisioning> iter = beans.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  try{
    UserProvisioning userProvisioning = iter.next();
    System.out.println(userProvisioning.getFIRST_NAME());
    list.add(userProvisioning);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    logger.warn("An issue occurred when looping through user provisionings: " + ex.getMessage());

  }
}
```

The above code will setup an iterator and loop through it. If an exception occurs it will log and continue the loop since no `break` was called.

also since you tell what type the iterator is, there is no need to cast it when you call `iter.next()`

Comment: suppose there are 10 total lines in CSV and error is at line number 3 then above code logs an error for line number three and loop do not continue for 4th csv record.

Comment: The above code will continue to the 4th CSV record unless something is actually throwing an `Error` Instead of an `Exception` in which change `Exception` to `Throwable`

Comment: You added more context since my answer, but `iter.next()` is within the `try-catch` block so if it fails to call next, it will still continue on;